# Database for bus routes

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a search function for bus routes. I have created an index page:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<body>
Enter info below:
<br />
<form action='routes.php' action='get'>

Start Destination:
<select name="start">
 <option value="StopA">Stop A</option>  
</select>
<br />
End Destination:
<select name="stop">
 <option value="StopZ">Stop Z</option>
</select>

Departing between (start):
<select name="start_time">
 <option value="13:40">13:40</option>
 <option value="13:45">13:45</option>
 <option value="13:50">13:50</option>
 <option value="13:55">13:55</option>
</select>
<br />
Departing between (end):
<select name="end_time">
 <option value="13:40">13:40</option>
 <option value="13:45">13:45</option>
 <option value="13:50">13:50</option>
 <option value="13:55">13:55</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and a 'routes' page which connects to my database

```
<?php
mysql_connect('', '', '');
$start = $_GET['start'];
$stop = $_GET['stop'];
$start_time = $_GET['start_time'];
$end_time = $_GET['end_time'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine.times where STOP_1 = '$start' and   STOP_7 = '$stop' and time(time) between '$start_time' and '$end_time'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Departure Time</th> <th>Route No.</th> <th>Stop 1</th> <th>Stop 2</th>       <th>Stop 3</th> <th>Stop 4</th> <th>Stop 5</th> </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['time'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['route_no'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['STOP_1'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['STOP_2'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['STOP_3'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['STOP_4'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['STOP_5'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 
echo $row['STOP_6'];
echo "</td></tr>";
echo $row['STOP_7'];
echo "</td></tr>";
} 

echo "</table>";

?>
```

when i search from my starting bus stop to the end bus stop i get no results.

my database looks like so:

```
time(PM) STOP_1 STOP_2 STOP_3 STOP_4 STOP_5 STOP_6 STOP_7 route_no.
13:00     
13:20
13:40
14:00
```

Is this correct?  Can anyone see if where the issue is with my code or if anyone has any suggestions on how to better it i would be very grateful.

Kind Regards, Key

Comment: Attention: you have a sql-injection security problem. You use the input, which is always unsafe, and put it unchecked inside the sql string. Please make sure you understand sql injection before put this on a public server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in `and time(time)` change it to with backticks 
as **time** is a keyword it should be used like  `` time(`time`) ``

Comment: hi,i tried that but still no luck. does the way the database is set out look ok to you?